# mysql count groupings

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_entities` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
....
  `created` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am trying to create a query that gives me the count of records by day.. e.g

```
Day 1: 23 
Day 2: 343 
etc...
```

Please note the output is not the exact format I want, just a display of what data I want.

Answer (score 2):

While writing the question I realised just how easy this is....

`SELECT COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y%m%d') AS testgroup FROM articles_entities GROUP BY testgroup;`